# Webpack process/browser in prod vs dev for Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I've been working with a Gatsby repo and I noticed that on some occasions if not all of the time when I call window, my deployment will fail with the following error

```
4:57:03 AM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 1.305s
4:57:03 AM: error "window" is not available during server side rendering.
4:57:03 AM: 
4:57:03 AM:   21 | }
4:57:03 AM:   22 | else {
4:57:03 AM: > 23 |     _btoa = btoa.bind(window);
4:57:03 AM:      | ^
4:57:03 AM:   24 |     helpers = function (url) {
4:57:03 AM:   25 |         return new URL(url);
4:57:03 AM:   26 |     };
4:57:03 AM: 
4:57:03 AM:   WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - helpers.js:23 
4:57:03 AM:     [gatsby-starter-default]/[web3-providers-ws]/lib/helpers.js:23:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - index.js:24 
4:57:03 AM:     [gatsby-starter-default]/[web3-providers-ws]/lib/index.js:24:15
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - index.js:44 
4:57:03 AM:     [gatsby-starter-default]/[web3-core-requestmanager]/lib/index.js:44:24
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - index.js:22 
4:57:03 AM:     [gatsby-starter-default]/[web3-core]/lib/index.js:22:24
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - index.js:29 
4:57:03 AM:     [gatsby-starter-default]/[web3]/lib/index.js:29:12
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
4:57:03 AM:   
4:57:03 AM:   - bootstrap:19 
4:57:03 AM:     gatsby-starter-default/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
```

This seems to be rectified by removing the bottom process/browser in my `gatsby-node.js` file which currently looks like this

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if(stage === "build-htmnl") {
        actions.setWebpackConfig({
            plugins: [
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                    process: 'process/browser',
                }),
            ],
        })
    }
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Buffer: [require.resolve("buffer/"), "Buffer"],
                process: 'process/browser',
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                "crypto": false,
                "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
                "assert": false,
                "util": false,
                "http": false,
                "https": false,
                "os": false
            },
        },
    })
}
```

But once I do that, it appears to break dev with my `useEffect` not executing properly nor the function I have attached as an onClick event to a button. The error I get is the following: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined`

Is there a way I can resolve this issue more easily? I'm not too familiar with webpack and how Gatsby interacts with it even less so. I would imagine it's as simple as a condition whether the app is in dev or prod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [Adding a Custom webpack Config docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/), `stage` value can mutate through:

> - develop: when running the `gatsby develop` command. Has configuration for hot reloading and CSS injection into page
> - develop-html: same as develop but without react-hmre in the babel config for rendering the HTML component.
> - build-javascript: production JavaScript and CSS build. Creates route JavaScript bundles as well as common chunks for JavaScript and CSS.
> - build-html: production build static HTML pages

So, yes, as you pointed, adding a simple condition should work to set the `process/browse` like:

```
if(stage === "develop"){
  // gatsby develop stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you again! It looks like all I would need to do is change `if (stage === "build-html")` to `if (stage === "build-html" || stage === "develop")` to solve my issue.